# The map between modules having unique top and socle

Tags: modules, representation-theory

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over field k. $M,N$ are $A$-modules such that $M$ has a unique simple top $S(M)$ and $N$ has a unique simple socle $S(N)$.

Now given a nonzero map $f: M \rightarrow N$, then how to get that $S(M)$ must occur in a composition series of $N$ and $S(N)$ must occur in a composition series of $M$?(Since $M$ has a unique simple top, it has a composition series of the form $0 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq radM \subseteq M$, then I think $f(radM) \not= f(M)$, and $f(M)/f(radM)$ is simple, so $f(M)/f(radM) \cong S(M)$， but I can't prove my idea, also I don't know whether it is the right way to get the conclusion, thank you for any help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $M/\ker f\cong f(M)\subset N$. Since $M$ has a unique maximal submodule, and $\ker f\neq M$, $S(M)$ it the simple top of $M/\ker f$. In particular, $S(M)$ occurs as a composition factor in $f(M)$. So, piece together a composition series for $f(M)$ and $N/f(M)$ (using the correspondence theorem) to get a composition series for $N$ containing $S(M)$.

In the other direction, $f(M)$ has simple socle (being a submodule of $N$), so $S(N)$ is the simple socle of $M/\ker f$. Now, piece together a composition series for $\ker f$ and $M/\ker f$ to get a composition series for $M$ containing $S(N)$ as a composition factor.